# Cannot create new directory or file in Qt Creator.3.0 when creating a plain c/c++ project

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt-creator

This is a strange problem, when I create a plain C/C++ project in Qt Creator, I can not create new source file or new directory; anybody know why? thanks~

My Qt Creator info:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 X86_64

Qt Creator 3.3.0 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.4.0 (GCC 4.6.1, 64 bit)

Built on Dec 8 2014 at 15:21:39

From revision d36c4d87db

Copyright 2008-2014 Digia Plc. All rights reserved.

Comment: what's the error message? in what circumstances did creating a file work?

Comment: there no error, just can not create

Comment: find a way to add information. is the 'create' command disabled? can you experiment to find some other set of circumstances where it's possible to add a resource? it's not possible to solve without more information. it could be a permissions problem, such as attempting to create a file as a regular user within a parent directory owned by root (or another user). it could be a lot of things.